# How can I perform operation over model field and filter in django?

Tags: django, orm

My model has a field named **key**, it looks like;

`key = models.CharField(max_length=64)`

I store encrypted string generated using pycrypto python package into **key** field.

`key = encrypted string of string 'abc'`

Now I try to filter over model using field **key** with encrypted string of same string, does not get any record beacaus each time i encrypt string 'abc' get different encrypted string.

`model.objects.filter(key=new encrypted string of abc)`

is that any way to perform decryption operation into model field and filter out using plain string like

`model.objects.filter(operation on key = 'abc')`

or do I need to go with any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. Alternatively use `django-searchable-encrypted-fields` package.

**[django-searchable-encrypted-fields 0.1.9](https://pypi.org/project/django-searchable-encrypted-fields/)**

> pip install django-searchable-encrypted-fields

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ["encrypted_fields"]

# A list of hex-encoded 32 byte keys
# You only need one unless/until rotating keys
FIELD_ENCRYPTION_KEYS = [
    "f164ec6bd6fbc4aef5647abc15199da0f9badcc1d2127bde2087ae0d794a9a0b"
]
```

Django model fields encrypted using `Pycryptodome AES-256 GCM`.

**models.py:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    _name_data = fields.EncryptedCharField(max_length=50, default="", null=True/False)
    name = fields.SearchField(hash_key="f164ec6bd...794a9a0b", encrypted_field_name="_name_data")
    favorite_number = fields.EncryptedIntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255) # regular Django model field
```

**You can then use it like:**

> "Jo" is hashed and stored in 'name' as well as symmetrically encrypted
> and stored in '_name_data'

> Person.objects.create(name="Jo", favorite_number=7,city="London")

> person = Person.objects.get(name="Jo")

> assert person.name == "Jo"

> assert person.favorite_number == 7

> person = Person.objects.get(city="London")

> assert person.name == "Jo" . # the data is taken from '_name_data', which decrypts it first.

Please read documentation once a time.